# Iphone - UISwitch Turned Off On Exit

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I want to set a switch to off when the app enters into background.  I am trying to do it using the following code.  It isn't working :(  When I resume app the switch is still "on" on animation on the screen.  How can I fix this?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [registrationSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the value in userDefaults. Add a boolean check like:

```
if (userDefaultBool == 1){
registrationSwitch setOn
}

else{
registration setOff
}
```

put that in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Just so I follow, I will just change the "userBool" value and then the viewDidLoad will correspondingly change the graphic? Correct?

Comment: exactly, so each time the switch is turned on or off, it sets it in userDefaults, then userDefaults tells the switch to set itself.